# href with onClick in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As per Reactjs.org to handle event and prevent default use below code:

```js
function ActionLink() {
  function handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('The link was clicked.');
  }
  return (
    <a href="#" onClick={handleClick}>
      Click me
    </a>
  );
}
```

However, this also requires to add binding in constructor like:

```
this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
```

I was able to get desired behaviour by below code:

```js
<span>
  <a href="#" onClick={()=>doSomething(arg1,agr2)}>Click here</a>
</span>
```

*Question:* Which one is better option? It seems first one requires to use stateful component and second option can do the things irrespective of component being stateful or stateless.

Comment: The second has a flaw similar to doing `onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}` in the first, where a new function is created on each render.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Both options produce almost the same result. Since ActionLink is a stateless component, `handleClick` will be re-created and `onClick` reallocated. If you want to get the best performance, you can use a class, something like this:

```
class ActionLink extends React.Component () {
  handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('The link was clicked.');
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <a href="#" onClick={this.handleClick}>
        Click me
      </a>
    );
  }
}
```

In this example. the `handleClick` is bound only once, and only the render method will be executed. You can also bind the `handleClick` in the constructor if you prefer. But the differences are so small that I would suggest you use the one you prefer and you find it clearer.

Comment: React gives a warning that `href="#"` "requires a valid value to be accessible."

Answer (score 5):

the best way to fix this repeated function call on page load is to do

```
<a href="#" onClick={() => {this.handleClick}}>click me</a>
```

Comment: It looks like you left off the `()` to call `handleClick`.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, if i had `href="#"` i was being redirected anyway, so i left my link/button like this:

```
<a href="" role="button" onClick={this.myAction}>Click here</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

using this code will produce a warning

```
<a href="#" onClick={() => action()}>Link</a>
```

there is a workaround this by following react cli advice and it is that if you cannot provide a valid link address with HTTP: etc to change your  tag to a button. It is possible to make a button look like a link with pure CSS. here is the example.

step one create the button styles

```
const buttonToLink = {
        fontSize: '1em',
        textAlign: 'left',
        color: 'blue',
        background: 'none',
        margin: 0,
        padding: 0,
        border: 'none',
        cursor: 'pointer'
     
    }
```

step 2 add the styles to the button

```
<button style={buttonToLink} onClick={() => action()}> This link has no warning</button>
```

Please note that "action()" is the function we want the button to follow.

Comment: Button should be preferred when need to execute Javascript code without navigation: https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/anchor-is-valid.md

Answer (score 1):

There is a slight performance issue with ---the second--- both snippets. Every time you render that `<a>` tag the function in the `onClick` will be reallocated.

Here is a detailed post outlining all the ways to bind `this` in react. (https://medium.com/@housecor/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56#.53op90a6w)

---

Edited. I misinterpreted the example code, it has the same issue of allocating the function on each render as the inline arrow function snippet. Refer [Vincent D'amour](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5103346/vincent-damour)'s accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should bind with current object. let it try. refer the following example:

```
<a href="#" onClick={this.handleclick.bind(this)}>click me</a>
```