# How to have a button on-click without a button look?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using React for a button. I would like it to not look like a button. Is there any way to have it be a clickable div without the button look? Here is my code:

```
<div style={styles.header}>
    <Button.Group >
        <Button onClick={this.refreshMyStuff}> Refresh </Button>
    </Button.Group>
</div>
```

Comment: _Is there any way to have it be a clickable div without the button look?_ Sure. Any visible block may be clickable and have `onClick` handler.

Comment: Not actually a duplicate, but maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42962603/href-with-onclick-in-reactjs) can help you. TL;DR: use a `div` instead of a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    console.log('clicked');
  }
  
  render() {
    return ( 
          <div className="button" onClick={this.handleClick}>Click me</div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( <
  App / > ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
.button {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<div id="root" />
```